# I am a newbie to Tor and don't understand coding. I need help with this error log on Tor

Tags: protocol

```
2/7/2017 12:19:59 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
2/7/2017 12:25:07 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:25:07 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:25:07 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:25:08 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
2/7/2017 12:25:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:25:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:25:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:25:13 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:25:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:25:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:25:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:25:55 PM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
2/7/2017 12:26:37 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:26:37 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:26:37 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:26:37 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:26:39 PM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host 2391AC90CC728EA9F20E5CFCA389C1F9FD7B16D2 at 193.24.209.70:443) 
2/7/2017 12:26:39 PM.500 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
2/7/2017 12:26:39 PM.500 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in CLOSED 
2/7/2017 12:26:39 PM.500 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
2/7/2017 12:26:39 PM.500 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/7/2017 12:26:41 PM.200 [WARN] The connection to the HTTP proxy server at 172.16.20.216:8090 just failed. Make sure that the proxy server is up and running. 
2/7/2017 12:26:41 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:26:41 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/7/2017 12:26:41 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/7/2017 12:26:41 PM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tor bridge https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en
Are you using tor browser bundle or installing the tor protocol?
Also make sure you have the latest version installed.
https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

Comment: Am using Tor browser bundle. And have sophos firewall, so can't access torproject.org. What do i do?

Comment: Onion menu -> Network Settings -> My ISP blocks..., then try the defaults (obfs4 or meek if obfs4 doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a very slow connection to the Tor directories, but it works - usually you need a bridges/pluggable transports when you have stuck on 10-15 percents in bootstrapping - and you have 85% done. Try to "seed" this Tor instance through another working connection - it will make a cache and it can help you. If you will add some more details about your case maybe I'll be able to give you a more detailed answer.